# How to find all rows with time to a datetime with timezone info?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a datetime column `dt` with the dtype `datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]`.

I am trying to find all rows with the time `2023-01-01 12:00:00-05:00`.

I tried to do this:

```
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
query_dt = datetime.datetime(year=2023, month=1, day=1, hour=12, minute=0, tzinfo=eastern)
df_sub = df[df.dt == query_dt]
```

But this is telling me there are no rows corresponding to `query_dt`, which is not correct as I can clearly see there are rows with that time.

Comment: Hi. Do you mind providing your `df.head(2).to_dict()` ?

Comment: @rafaelc yeah it is `{0: Timestamp('2022-12-01 09:45:00-0500', tz='US/Eastern'),
 1: Timestamp('2022-12-01 10:00:00-0500', tz='US/Eastern')}`

Comment: IIRC, using `pytz` in the standard `datetime` constructor is buggy. We had questions about that before, let me find one